# Error on Riak ( 2.1.1 ) startup

Tags: riak

### I have an error trying to start riak after compiled it from the source code (riak 2.1.1).

soft67:bin Humberto$ ./riak start 
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 2560; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.

### If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.

I am using gcc 5.2 as default compiler, OS X Yosemite 10.10 and the Basho's patched version of Erlang (OTP_R16B02_basho8)

What is wrong? I did the same in Ubunto 14.4 and works OK

I have this error with the lib eleveldb.so:

2015-07-30 12:43:59.292 [warning] <0.191.0> The on_load function for module eleveldb returned {error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(/Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZTTNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE\n  Referenced from: /Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so'"}}

I used otool to see the links of eleveldb.so, here is the output:

soft67:bin Humberto$ otool -L /Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so
/Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so:
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.21.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

## Compiler information

Humbertos-MacBook-Pro-2:Humberto$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc5/gcc5/work/gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc5 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc5 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0'
Thread model: posix

## gcc version 5.2.0 (MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0)

## Erlang information

soft67:bin Humberto$ erl
Erlang R16B02_basho8 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.3  (abort with ^G)

## 1>

## Console log

2015-07-30 16:54:58.993 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.001 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.001 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.004 [info] <0.7.0> Application crypto started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.004 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.010 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.013 [info] <0.7.0> Application riak_sysmon started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.021 [info] <0.7.0> Application os_mon started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.028 [info] <0.70.0> alarm_handler: {set,{system_memory_high_watermark,[]}}
2015-07-30 16:54:59.030 [info] <0.7.0> Application runtime_tools started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.062 [info] <0.7.0> Application erlang_js started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.062 [info] <0.7.0> Application xmerl started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.078 [info] <0.7.0> Application inets started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.078 [info] <0.7.0> Application mochiweb started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.084 [info] <0.7.0> Application webmachine started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.084 [info] <0.7.0> Application basho_stats started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.090 [info] <0.7.0> Application bitcask started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.100 [info] <0.7.0> Application clique started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.100 [info] <0.7.0> Application eleveldb started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.101 [info] <0.7.0> Application pbkdf2 started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.101 [info] <0.7.0> Application poolboy started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.125 [info] <0.158.0>@exometer_report:do_start_reporters:613 Starting reporters with []
2015-07-30 16:54:59.126 [info] <0.7.0> Application exometer_core started on node 'riak@127.0.0.1'
2015-07-30 16:54:59.185 [warning] <0.178.0>@riak_core_ring_manager:reload_ring:359 No ring file available.
2015-07-30 16:54:59.222 [warning] <0.191.0> The on_load function for module eleveldb returned {error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library: 'dlopen(/Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7leveldb13gPerfCountersE\n  Referenced from: /Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Users/Humberto/riak-2.1.1/rel/riak/bin/../lib/eleveldb-2.1.0-0-ga36dbd6/priv/eleveldb.so'"}}
2015-07-30 16:54:59.223 [error] <0.189.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.189.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function eleveldb:destroy("./data/cluster_meta/trees", []) in gen_server:init_it/6 line 328
2015-07-30 16:54:59.223 [error] <0.164.0> Supervisor riak_core_sup had child riak_core_metadata_hashtree started with riak_core_metadata_hashtree:start_link() at undefined exit with reason call to undefined function eleveldb:destroy("./data/cluster_meta/trees", []) in context start_error
2015-07-30 16:54:59.223 [error] <0.162.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.162.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,riak_core_metadata_hashtree,{undef,[{eleveldb,destroy,["./data/cluster_meta/trees",[]],[]},{hashtree,destroy,1,[{file,"src/hashtree.erl"},{line,275}]},{hashtree_tree,create_node,2,[{file,"src/hashtree_tree.erl"},{line,463}]},{hashtree_tree,new,2,[{file,"src/hashtree_tree.erl"},{line,193}]},{riak_core_metadata_hashtree,init,1,[{file,"src/riak_core_metadata_hashtree.erl"},{line,172}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,...}]}}},...} in application_master:init/4 line 133
2015-07-30 16:54:59.223 [info] <0.7.0> Application riak_core exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,riak_core_metadata_hashtree,{undef,[{eleveldb,destroy,["./data/cluster_meta/trees",[]],[]},{hashtree,destroy,1,[{file,"src/hashtree.erl"},{line,275}]},{hashtree_tree,create_node,2,[{file,"src/hashtree_tree.erl"},{line,463}]},{hashtree_tree,new,2,[{file,"src/hashtree_tree.erl"},{line,193}]},{riak_core_metadata_hashtree,init,1,[{file,"src/riak_core_metadata_hashtree.erl"},{line,172}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,...}]}}},...}
2015-07-30 16:54:59.225 [info] <0.70.0> alarm_handler: {clear,system_memory_high_watermark}

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem with Riak 1.4, and I found the reason is my Erlang version is built by **llvm-gcc**, but Riak 1.4 requires **gnu-gcc**. When Riak start, program would failed with load certain lib.

Strongly recommend install Erlang refer to basho doc:

- [Installing-on-Mac-OS-X](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/#Installing-on-Mac-OS-X)
- [Install-Riak](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/#Install-Riak)

As your OSX is 10.10, compile Erlang from source with configure below:

```
./configure --disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads \
--enable-kernel-poll  --enable-darwin-64bit
```

After all, recompile Riak.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu system, run the following command

```
export WAIT_FOR_ERLANG=60
```

Answer (score 0):

The other OSX option would be to use a pre-compiled version of Riak such as Riak-2.9.8 from https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.9/2.9.8/osx/10.14/

If Riak starts and dies a few seconds later, have a look at `var/console.log` to see if Riak is complaining about `crypto`. If so, copy the two dylib files available from the same site to `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` and it should be happy.